# meteor- should I create new collection or extend the user profile?

Tags: meteor

So I have an application that allows users to invite each other to different events. Previously I had a separate collection called Invites that contained an entry for each user and an array of events they were invited to. Since I'm building a prototype, I have insecure on, and I would simply update Invites from the client side.

Recently I changed this so that when a user invites another to an event, it calls a meteor method and updates both the inviter and the invitee's profiles on the client side.

Now my app is running very slowly and I'm not sure why. Even just loading the first page of the app (the login button for example, which uses accounts UI takes forever to load). Since the changes to invitations are the only changes I've made, I'm guessing this is the issue. Is storing invitations on each user's profile the wrong way to go about this? Any ideas about how to debug this slowness? I'm new to meteor/ web dev in general and I'm not sure what the best practices are for writing efficient code.

Comment: I think this question is too broad for this format, but in general my advice is to not update the users collection for transactional data. Instead, you should either add an invitations collection or add an array of invitation objects to documents in the events collection. E.g. `invitations: [{userId: 'abc123', invitedBy: 'xyz321'}]`.

Comment: Check out kadira.io to find why your app is so slow.

Comment: How can we know why your app is slow without seeing any code, profile, performance report? And StackOverflow is not the right place to come ask for "the right thing to do" as it is generally too opinionated.